# EZproxy Not sending cookie data with ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies

Im Having some issues with EZproxy. When accessing my site via EZproxy only some of the Ajax requests are being sent with the cookie data. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how i can fix this issue.

Many thanks in advance

Billy

Comment: what is EZproxy and where is it used?

Comment: From what i understand, EZproxy is a proxy server. I think we are using it to rewrite the urls and forward requests to our site. The problem we have is that our site is sending ajax requests. some of these requests are returning with a 200 and some are returning with a 401. from the logs i can see that the requests that are returning a 401 are not being sent with the users credentials. These credentials are stores in a cookie.

Comment: are requests being made cross domain? If so would need to set `withCredentials` header